# The person was made particularly understood not to enter the premise due to its extensive renovation

Tags: verbs

Is the phrase

> made particularly understood?

grammatically correct?

Apparently, my grammar checker checked it correct.

Or is the correct sentence

> That person was particularly made to understand?

Thank you for the guidance

Comment: Your grammar checker is 'talking' nonsense. It was the person who did the understanding.

Comment: Your title sentence is gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is grammatical, and your grammar checker needs to take its medications more regularly. "X was forced to do Y" is the equivalent of "X was made to do Y" rather "X was made done Y." The latter is beyond barbaric.

Being grammatical does not make it ideal. I have always found the phrase "made to understand" unsatisfactory because lacking in necessary detail. How was the information to be understood conveyed: formal instruction, example, extrasensory perception? Furthermore, how was it determined that the information conveyed was fully and correctly received? The phrase strikes me as both evasive and pompous.